# GdxRuntimeException uiskin.atlas

Tags: android, libgdx, texture-atlas

I have problem when trying to use the uiskin.atlas from github/libgdx. I've downloaded(cloned) it from libgdx.git but it just doesnt work.

I get the following error:
Com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading pack file: data/uiskin.atlas

And further down in the catlog it says:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 256,128 is not a constant in com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap$Format

What does that mean?
Anyone knows how to solve it?

Im using the line 
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));

Im at work at the moment so can't give more info than this. The error happens both in Eclipse and in AIDE on my phone.

Comment: Got it to work.

Comment: Had an old version of libgdx. Got it to work with the old version too if I removed the line "Size: 256, 128". Then I got an error in json file but removing a line there too solved the problem. But updating version was even better :-)